# Sign and broadcast smart contract transaction in TRON network

Tags: blockchain, digital-signature, tron, tronweb

Using a node.js client, I'm trying to invoke a smart contract function by:

1. Creating a transaction
2. Signing it
3. Broadcast the signed transaction

I deployed a simple smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Test {
    event MyEvent(address sender, string message, uint sessionId, uint value);
    event TestEvent(address sender);

    constructor() public {}

    function testFunction(string message, uint sessionId)
    public payable {
        emit MyEvent(msg.sender, message, sessionId, msg.value);
    }

    function test2()
    public {
        emit TestEvent(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

I'm having success invoking `test2` (when sending an empty parameters array) but failing to invoke `testFunction` which takes parameters. I've tried using [tronweb triggerSmartContract call](https://developers.tron.network/reference#triggersmartcontract):

```js
async function triggerSmartContract() {
    try {
        const options = {
            feeLimit: 1000000000,
            callValue: 50
        };

        const parameters = [{type: 'string', value: 'test-round-id-1'}, {type: 'uint', value: 12345}];
        const issuerAddress = tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58;
        const functionSelector = 'testFunction(string, uint)';

        let transactionObject = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.triggerSmartContract (
            contract_address,
            functionSelector,
            options,
            parameters,
            tronWeb.address.toHex(issuerAddress)
        );

        if (!transactionObject.result || !transactionObject.result.result) {
            return console.error('Unknown error: ' + txJson, null, 2);
        }

        // Signing the transaction
        const signedTransaction = await tronWeb.trx.sign(transactionObject.transaction);

        if (!signedTransaction.signature) {
            return console.error('Transaction was not signed properly');
        }

        // Broadcasting the transaction
        const broadcast = await tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction);
        console.log(`broadcast: ${broadcast}`);
    } catch (e) {
        return console.error(e);
    }
}
```

The code runs and creates a transaction on the blockchain but with result of `FAIL-REVERT OPCODE EXECUTED`.
The wallet  of the address and key that are defined in tronweb object has enough funds in it (it's not out of gas/not enough funds matter).
Also the function in the smart contract is defined as payable.

Since I can invoke successfully any function with no parameters I tend to think the problem relates to the way I construct the `parameters` array. I built the `parameters` array this way (pairs of `type` and `value`) after going over the [source code of the transactionBuilder (line 833)](https://github.com/TRON-US/tronweb/blob/master/src/lib/transactionBuilder.js).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try writing function parameters without spaces.`const functionSelector = 'testFunction(string,uint)';` I read in the documentation that you have to write without spaces, it worked for me on python.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same issue. Solution:

1. Remove spaces in `const functionSelector = 'testFunction(string,uint)';` as malysh advised
2. Change `uint` to `uint256`